# VLCJ code not compiling with latest vlcj-javafx jar

Tags: javafx, vlcj, vlcj-javafx

I am attempting to run the VLCJ JavaFX demo program that is provided at

```
https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/javafx/demo/VlcjJavaFxApplication.java
```

I am running this program on a Windows 10 machine.

The program apparently runs without problems using older versions of vlcj-javafx (like V1.0.1).

Unfortunately, the demo does not compile as is on the latest version of vlcj-javafx (1.1.0). Apparently, when attempting to use the same demo in V1.1.0, I get the following compilation error:

```
 The import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.javafx.videosurface.ImageViewVideoSurfaceFactory cannot be resolved
```

which means that the function:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    this.videoImageView = new ImageView();
    this.videoImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

    embeddedMediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(videoSurfaceForImageView(this.videoImageView));
}
```

will not compile.

Obviously, there has been a change in the EmbeddedMediaPlayer's videoserface API that has not been updated in the demo program, and my search through the Internet has not yielded any demo vlcj-javafx demo programs that utilize V1.1.0 of vlcj-javafx.

So: can someone provide the change(s) necessary to make a video player work using vlcj-javafx V1.1.0? Do I need to change the import statement? Is there a different factory I am supposed to use?

Comment: You might check your branch and library version, as suggested [here](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx-demo).